# SIGILL occurs when using remote debbuging on arm target even if handle SIGILL nostop is set

Tags: c++, openssl, arm, gdb, remote-debugging

I'm trying to remote debug a c++ app from a windows host to a debian armbian target of cubietruck board (ARM® Cortex™-A7 Dual-Core). However the debbuger breaks while receiving SIGILL. I've searched and found the reason. It is described in this post [SSL_library_init cause SIGILL when running under gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25708907/ssl-library-init-cause-sigill-when-running-under-gdb).
My app also uses openssl. However I tried the `handle SIGILL nostop`  command both in the .gdbinit file as well in the native gdb but the debugger's breaking continued due to this signal. I also tried handle `SIGINT nostop` but the situation didn't change. 
I also update the gdb to latest version 8.0.1 but didn't solve the problem as well.
I'm wondering if someone has found another way to bypass this issue.

Comment: @old_timer Yes you are right it is ARM® Cortex™-A7 Dual-Core, I will update